# VB 2010, how to remove data source?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm using VB 2010. Added a data source. You can see it in the "Data Sources" window. There are options to refresh and add more data sources. But no option to remove a data source. Obviously I'm missing something. How do I remove a data source?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to remove the "data source" from the project. The "Data Sources" tool window shows what data-sources are available in the solution/project.